# matching data from one data frame to another

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to do the below, I had originally posted a simpler version of this thinking it would generalize but have now realized it won't and so am reposting the problem here

The original question (and solutions) can be found here: [Matching data from one data frame to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065503/matching-data-from-one-data-frame-to-another)

I have two data frames, dfa and dfb

```
IDa <- c(1,2,3)
score1a <- c(5,10,1)
score2a <- c(NA,8,NA)
score3a <- c(NA,NA,13)
score1b <- c(NA,4,9)
score2b <- c(2,3,NA)
score2c <- c(1,5,1)
score3c <- c(6,NA,1)

dfa <- data.frame(IDa,score1a,score2a,score3a,score1b,score2b,score2c,score3c)

IDb <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
timeb <- c(1,2,3,2,3,3)

dfb <- data.frame(IDb,timeb)
```

In score1a, the '1' represents timeb = 1 in dfb and 'a' represents the first test type (hence there are 3 types of test, a,b,c and 3 timepoints 1,2,3)

I want to take the data from dfa and add this to dfb to create something like dfc below (note the first two columns of dfc are identical to dfb)

```
IDc <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
timec <- c(1,2,3,2,3,3)
scorea <- c(5,NA,NA,8,NA,13)
scoreb <- c(NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA)
scorec <- c(NA,1,6,5,NA,1)

dfc <- data.frame(IDc, timec, scorea, scoreb, scorec)
```

Hope that makes sense, many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using dplyr and tidyr:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

gather(dfa, xx, timea, -IDa) %>%
  mutate(xx = as.character(xx),
         x = gsub("[0-9]", "", xx)) %>%
  spread(x, timea) %>%
  mutate(xx = as.numeric(gsub("[a-zA-Z]", "", xx))) %>%
  group_by(IDa, xx) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)]))) %>%
  left_join(dfb, ., by = c("IDb" = "IDa", "timeb" = "xx"))

#  IDb timeb scorea scoreb scorec
#1   1     1      5     NA     NA
#2   1     2     NA      2      1
#3   1     3     NA     NA      6
#4   2     2      8      3      5
#5   2     3     NA     NA     NA
#6   3     3     13     NA      1
```

The following steps are made (per line of code):

1. gather: Reshape (gather) the data from wide to long format, new columns will be named "xx" and "timea"
2. Mutate: turn the column "xx" into a character column (previously a factor)
3. Still Mutate: create a new column "x" based on the column "xx" but all numbers from xx are removed
4. Spread: reshape the data from long to wide based on the new "x" column
5. Mutate: remove all characters from "xx" and store the rest (numbers in character format) as numeric numbers
6. group_by: group the data by "IDa" and "xx"
7. summarise_each: within each group (by IDa and xx), and for each column except the grouping variables IDa and xx: take the *first* element which is *not* NA. More explicitly: the `.[!is.na(.)]` removes all NA entries from the data and then the `first()` function wrapped around it, takes the first element of the data without NAs. And generally, `summarise` and `summarise_each` will break the data down to 1 row for each group (which in this case will hold the first non-NA entry).
8. left_join: perform a left join of dfb with the previously computed data (note the order inside the left_join, which is important here) by the ID columns and timeb and xx, respectively.

Edit 2

Here are some examples to better understand what the `first(.[!is.na(.)])` part does. Just remember that in the code, the `.` represents the grouped data that is passed to the function (equivalent to what I call `x` in the examples below).

```
set.seed(99)
x <- sample(10)  #create a vector with random numbers
x
#[1]  6  2 10  7  4  5  3  1  8  9

x[sample(10, 4, replace = F)] <- NA  # add some NAs
x
#[1]  6 NA 10  7 NA NA  3  1 NA  9 

is.na(x)  # is the value in each in index/place of x equal to NA?
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

x[is.na(x)]   # show me the values of x which are NA (of course, they are NA)
#[1] NA NA NA NA

x[!is.na(x)]  # show me the values of x which are not NA (== remove NAs)
#[1]  6 10  7  3  1  9

dplyr::first(x[!is.na(x)])  # of all the values in x which are not NA, return the first one
#[1] 6

x[!is.na(x)][1]  # this is equivalent to the previous line but using [1] instead of first()
#[1] 6

head(x[!is.na(x)], 1)  # this is also equivalent of the two previous lines but using head(..., 1)
#[1] 6
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Could you expand on what this line is doing `summarise_each(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)])))`

Comment: @Impossible9, I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Is there anywhere I can find any more info about the `.[!is.na(.)]` syntax? I haven't seen `!is.na()` used in this way before (I don't really fully understand how the subsetting is working either) and have looked around but haven't been able to find anything

Comment: I don't really know a good thing to read about it, except maybe checking help("is.na") but I added some more explanation on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package along with `merge`.

Generally, reshape-related functions in R seem to like the names to be in the form of "type" + "time" (your variables are currently in the form of "time" + "type"). We can easily rename the columns to the desired form with `setnames` from "data.table" (which is loaded along with "splitstackshape").

```
library(splitstackshape)
setnames(dfa, gsub("(score)(\\d)([a-z])", "\\3_\\2", names(dfa)))
```

Once the names are correct, we stack the relevant columns and merge the results with your second dataset. A conversion to numeric was required to make the merge take place on the same types of data.

```
setkey(
  merged.stack(dfa, var.stubs = c("^a", "^b", "^c"), 
               sep = "_")[, .time_1 := as.numeric(.time_1)],
  IDa, .time_1)[setkeyv(as.data.table(dfb), names(dfb))]
#    IDa .time_1 ^a ^b ^c
# 1:   1       1  5 NA NA
# 2:   1       2 NA  2  1
# 3:   1       3 NA NA  6
# 4:   2       2  8  3  5
# 5:   2       3 NA NA NA
# 6:   3       3 13 NA  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @beginneR answer above but avoiding using the grouping/summarise_each:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

colnames(dfa)[-1] <- c("scorea1","scorea2","scorea3","scoreb1","scoreb2","scorec2","scorec3") 

dfa %>%
  gather(name, score, scorea1:scorec3) %>%
  separate(variable, c("score","time"), 6) %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>%
  spread(score, value) %>%
  left_join(dfb, ., by= c("IDb"="IDa", "timeb"="time"))
```